# How to send a value from js file and display in a HTML in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing an Event Handler using Angularjs. User can insert an event and the relevant date. All the details of an event will be stored in an array (which is in controller.js file). Then I need to find out the event with closest date to the current date and display it on the UI. ( I am displaying the all the other events using ng-repeat. Also I want to display this part as the upcoming event)

Since I am a newbie to Angularjs, I couldn't understand some solutions on the web. Can you suggest me a best solution to achieve this?
Also what is the best way to add a calendar to the UI?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use module like below which has afterWhere filter or write filter by your self to filter your events array by given date and filter out events after that date.

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

For calendar, use this module.

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/